# Unable to pick the values from Properties file and Bootstrap.yml in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wanted to pick the values from the **application.properties** and **bootstrap.yml** file. When I try to do so I am getting Null on the console. Please suggest whats wrong here.

**application.properties** is as follows

```
restcall.erp.name=erp
restcall.plant.name=plant
restcall.apikey.name=apikey
restcall.region.name=region
```

**bootstrap.yml** is as follows

```
apigee:
  api:
    key: someKey
  url:
    item:
      itemputurl: https://someAnotherUrl
```

**Java Code **

```
  package com.jci.itemjob.service.mapics;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;


//@RefreshScope
@Component
//@Configuration
//@ComponentScan
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:bootstrap.yml"),
})
public class MapicsSendAckToApigeeFromItemJob {


    @Value("${apigee.url.item.itemputurl}")
    private String itemPUTURL;

    @Value("${restcall.erp.name}")
    private String erpParam;

    @Value("${restcall.plant.name}")
    private String plantParam;

    @Value("${restcall.region.name}")
    private String regionParam;

    @Value("${restcall.apikey.name}")
    private String apiKeyParam;

    @Value("${restcall.params.key.headers}")
    private String headersParam;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MapicsSendAckToApigeeFromItemJob.class);

    public CloseableHttpResponse sendResponse(String apikey, String plant, String erp, String region,
            MapicsItemApigeePut itemApigeePut) {


        try {
            MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

            LOG.info("erp-----------------" + erpParam);
            LOG.info("plant-----------------" + plantParam);
            LOG.info("apikey-----------------" + apiKeyParam);
            LOG.info("region-----------------" + regionParam);
            LOG.info("itemPUTURL-----------------" + itemPUTURL);

            //Other Logic
```

The Output is as below

```
item-job-mapics_1  | 2018-02-05 09:02:35.381  INFO 1 --- [nio-9011-exec-3] j.i.s.m.MapicsSendAckToApigeeFromItemJob : erp-----------------null
item-job-mapics_1  | 2018-02-05 09:02:35.381  INFO 1 --- [nio-9011-exec-3] j.i.s.m.MapicsSendAckToApigeeFromItemJob : plant-----------------null
item-job-mapics_1  | 2018-02-05 09:02:35.381  INFO 1 --- [nio-9011-exec-3] j.i.s.m.MapicsSendAckToApigeeFromItemJob : apikey-----------------null
item-job-mapics_1  | 2018-02-05 09:02:35.381  INFO 1 --- [nio-9011-exec-3] j.i.s.m.MapicsSendAckToApigeeFromItemJob : region-----------------null
item-job-mapics_1  | 2018-02-05 09:02:35.381  INFO 1 --- [nio-9011-exec-3] j.i.s.m.MapicsSendAckToApigeeFromItemJob : itemPUTURL-----------------null
```

Comment: please include the output of your program also!

Comment: I have also added `@PropertySources` in the code still the output is same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying you need to do all of that, but that's what I did... I created AppProperties class annotated

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app")
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
//  @PropertySource("classpath:application-local.properties"),
//  @PropertySource("classpath:application-dev.properties"),
//  @PropertySource("classpath:application-prod.properties"),
})
public class AppProperties {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

}
```

and in property file I have `app.name`.

ConfigurationProperties defines your prefix in configuration. Spring can find you property files automatically, but I found, when I have profile "dev" it is reading application-dev.properties only. With `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` it reads that file + profile specific one (which is something I was looking for).

Additionally I have one more class (which is empty):

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)
public class AppConfiguration {
}
```

Comment: For reading with regard to Environment  You can use Spring Profile approach. In this you need to read the values from Bootstrap.yml file instead of the application.properties file  Here is the code Snippet `server:
  port : 9011

spring:
  profiles:
    active: azure-development-cloud
---
spring:
  profiles: docker-development-cloud
  application:
    name: item-job-mapics
app:
  name: Anand
`

Comment: Is it not possible to without creating any Additional classes. ??

Comment: based on [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) it is, but I was not able to make it work...

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh I realized I have one more class, please check ;-)